# Is JSP not a good choice as a server side scripting language for consumer-scale multinational portals? e.g. for Facebook/Gmail scale or beyond?

Tags: scalability

The site/app would be AJAX heavy and will have UI MashUps. Would using an AJAX toolkit or lot of Javascript in the webpage go against scale goals, in other words, would more bandwidth consumption due to Javascript-heaviness would affect bottomline?

Sorry to ask two questions together, somehow they are related to overall SCALE goal at client tier.

Thanks in advance,
Deb

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your question is unclear.

You first ask about *JSP being a good choice*, then talk about *scalability*. The two must be treated separately.

JSP is a server-side platform, just as PHP and ASP.NET. According only to the **design** of your web application, it's perfectly scalable. Actually, you can choose any of the listed platforms if your goal is scalability, *plus* a little more hints.

Second, Javascript and bandwidth consumption. If you have a **good** (and I mean **good**) AJAX toolkit, then I suppose lots of JS contents are static. I mean lots of functions and  class libraries are stored in static JS file that don't change during software's lifetime, and that's exactly what we want!! The only part that change is the page-level scripting and the XMLHTTP responses.

Now, all the libraries can be **cached** by browsers, dramatically reducing bandwidth consumption.

## My hint

is to use a [static content domain](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/), possibly powered by a Content Distribution Network.

This will unload a lot your JSP-busy servers on a scalable application.

## Remember

Your web application must be correctly designed to be scalable (don't rely on session variables, for example)